# Type hinting of ENum created using API

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting

Type hinting works fine in `vscode` when the enum is created as follows:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    YELLOW = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

An enum can also be created from a dictionary using `Enum` API, and when created like this type hinting doesn't work:

```
from enum import Enum

color_values = dict(RED = 1, YELLOW = 2, GREEN = 3)
Color = Enum('Color', color_values, type=int)
```

How to get type hinting working when an `Enum` is created using its API?

Comment: You don't. Getting that to work in general would require running the Python code, which aside from being horribly inefficient also runs up against theoretical constraints like the halting problem. The type checker is there to handle the simple cases, not well-type every possible Python program that can ever be written.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This is not true at all. Python type-checkers does consider certain language constaines into acount even though they are considered "meta-programming" take `dataclass_transform()` i.e.  Any built in feature of the language in this case `Enum` should be supported by the type-checker.

Comment: You might want to check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74949000/how-to-type-enum-created-dynamically-with-a-default-value/74949019#74949019)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible without somehow running python while type checking.

Consider this example:

```
from enum import Enum

color_values = dict(RED = 1, YELLOW = 2, GREEN = 3)
key = "BLUE"
color_values[key] = 1
Color = Enum('Color', color_values, type=int)
```